# Monitoring different kinds of errors/logs on 100 servers

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a 100 servers running an application. This application logs certain important messages. I pull all the logs into 1 elastic search instance.

ex: "Condition A occurred due to value X", "Condition B occurred due to value Y"

I want to create a dashboard where I can see all the conditions that occurred and due to what value and on what machine.

ex:

- Condition A - 100 times in last 60 minutes
- Condition B - 12 times in last 60 minutes

And on clicking the visual element for condition A, I want to see a further breakdown

- Machine 1:   Condition A occurred due to value X    20 times
- Machine 2:   Condition A occurred due to value U    10 times, 
  Condition A occurred due to value X    06 times

I tried using Kibana for this, but was unable to figure out the right reg expressions.

Now I am thinking I may be using the wrong tool altogether. Can you guys guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need to be querying on a .raw field, or just using a parsed token as a query:

eg.   message.raw:"some text as it appears"     or     message:keyword

Beyond that, its hard to say without seeing some actual examples. But the bit you are likely missing is some processing/extraction in logstash or similar to pull out the bits of interest. Remember that Kibana is not for extracting date out of logs, its for extracting information out of indexed data.